# diagnose pool motor will not run

Tags: pool, electric-motor, capacitor

My pool motor (Haywood 1.0 HP Super Pump) stopped working a few days ago. At the time it was humming when power was on so I figured it was the start capacitor. I ordered a new one and checked the pump motor today and it made no noise at all... no hum. Nothing.

I replaced the capacitor and while I had it apart I checked that the shaft/impeller spun. It did spin, but with a slight resistance. I'm not sure how easily it should turn, but it seemed reasonably "loose" enough to work.

I checked the original start capacitor with my meter (after replacing it) and found it to be OK.

After reassembling the pump with the new capacitor, the motor still does nothing (and makes no noise) when I cut the power on.

Other devices on the same circuit (heater, salt module, pool lights) are getting power and seem to be functional.

There's no kind of circuit boards or other fancy controls or diagnostic displays. It's just directly wired (240v). I'm thinking the motor is cooked.

I have a decent quality multimeter that I know the basics of how to operate, but I don't really know how to use it to prove to myself that the motor is bad and requires the purchase of an expensive replacement. **How can I test the motor to know that it is shot?**

---

*I think it tested OK, but I took it fully apart and found that the shaft seal was damaged/installed incorrectly and several years of salt water leaking into the berings wrecked them. Replaced the motor.*

Comment: I will assume you did check to see if full voltage was available at the motor.  There should be some simple tests(ohms) shown online to check the motor, before tossing it.  I would also check if there is a local motor rebuilder close by.  Automotive alternator/starter places might help.

Comment: @crip659 No, I haven't checked the voltage yet, but that seems kind of remote. Are you talking voltage on the supply side, or in the motor?

Comment: Both, so you know it is not a problem with the wires/breaker.  As I said there should be a few simple tests you can do to see if it a tosser or a repairer.

Comment: @crip659 I do know that other devices downline from the switch (heater, salt system, pool lights) are working so I assumed that the pump was getting power too. What can you tell me about the "few simple tests"?

Comment: Open the filter cap (on top) use a wood stick, NOT fingers, and give it a spin then start motor while it is spinning. You are doing the start capacitor function that way.

Comment: @Ruskes I don't have access to the impeller without disassembling the pump. I have replaced the capacitor with a new one. I just checked the old capacitor and it seems to be OK as well.

Comment: How long was it humming ? probably longer than you know. It would have overheated. Disconnect the wires directly at the motor and use Ohm meter. You should not see infinite nor zero

Comment: Look for a thermal reset switch somewhere on the motor. This is usually a red plastic button about 3/16" square, sticking out about 1/2". If you find one, press it in to reset.

Comment: @MTA One of the first things I looked for. Unless it's internal, there doesn't seem to be one.